# OpenGL 2D Shape Issue

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl

I'm trying to make shapes with OpenGL in LWJGL but every time I do it, it makes this triangle dent in it.

The Code:

```
//The Window Is 800 Wide And 600 Tall
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glVertex2i(0, 0);
GL11.glVertex2i(800, 0);
GL11.glVertex2i(0, 600);
GL11.glVertex2i(800, 600);
GL11.glEnd();
```

The Result:

[image: The OpenGL Fail]

Also, the code was a lot bigger then that. I just put the code that draws the shape.

Comment: The dent is the problem.

Comment: Do you want a rectangular shape? Because I think the coordinates you defined are problematic.

Comment: What's the problem with the coordinates?

Comment: Nope, the coordinates are  a quad.May be winding issue?If you rotate the triangle to face its backside ,can you see the second triangle?

Answer (score 5):

Order of operations does matter in OpenGL. This code goes as follows:

Put down a "pencil" (I suggest you do this with a real pencil on an actual piece of paper, while reading this, i.e. following the instructions, put down the pencil and do the following movements without lifting it) – Draw a quad

```
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
```

First corner bottom left

```
GL11.glVertex2i(0, 0);
```

Second corner bottom right

```
GL11.glVertex2i(800, 0);
```

Thid corner top left

```
GL11.glVertex2i(0, 600);
```

Fourth corner top right

```
GL11.glVertex2i(800, 600);
```

Finish quad by returning with the pencil to the first point.

```
GL11.glEnd();
```

OpenGL expects you to deliver it convex geometry with a consistent winding, i.e. the vertices are drawn in clockwise or counterclockwise direction. You're switching directions inbetween, which makes the shape you define nonconvex.

I strongly suggest you keep to a counter clockwise winding:

1. Bottom Left
2. Bottom Right
3. Top Right
4. Top Left

That's also how you'd draw a quad with a pencil.

Comment: Why don't I get +1 ? I was the first ;)

Comment: @MichaelIV: Because it's chrismas eve I gave you a +1 present :)

Answer (score 4):

Try to swap these two:

```
 GL11.glVertex2i(0, 600);
 GL11.glVertex2i(800, 600);
```

So yo have this:

```
GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
GL11.glVertex2i(0, 0);
GL11.glVertex2i(800, 0);
GL11.glVertex2i(800, 600);
GL11.glVertex2i(0, 600);
GL11.glEnd();
```

So , in your code the vertex order in the quad is : top left , top right , bottom left , bottom right.Which is not a convex shape.
The correct order is :
 top left , top right , bottom right, bottom left.

Comment: It just changes the triangle position.

Comment: It comes up with the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I draw top left, top right, bottom right, bottom left. Not top left, top right, bottom left, bottom right.

Comment: So that is what I proposed you :) Your coordinates were : top left , top right , bottom left , bottom right.

Comment: FYI: Most OpenGL projection setups assume the origin, in the lower left corner, so positive Y values go up!